# Show that $V(y^5-x^2)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as a variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

This is an exercise from Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et al.

> Show that $V(y^5-x^2)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ as a variety by showing that there is no ring isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}[V]$ to $\mathbb{R}[t]$.

There is another proof in the textbook using pullback. This problem asks to show it without using that.

**Hint**:

1. Every element of $\mathbb{R}[V]$ can be written as $a(y)+b(y)x$.
2. Suppose there were some ring isomorphism $\alpha: \mathbb{R}[t]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[V]$, such that $\alpha(f(t))=x, \alpha(g(t))=y$. Using the unique factorization of $f,g$, deduce a contradiction.

**My attempt**:

I didn't do anything very helpful. Suppose $f,g$ has the following unique factorization in $\mathbb{R}[t]$:

$$f=f_1^{a_1}\cdots f_r^{a_r}\\
g=g_1^{b_1}\cdots g_s^{b_s}\\
x=\alpha(f)=\alpha(f_1)^{a_1}\cdots \alpha(f_r)^{a_r}\\
y=\alpha(g)=\alpha(g_1)^{b_1}\cdots \alpha(g_s)^{b_s}$$

I cannot see how to connect this with the representation in $\mathbb{R}[V]$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$V(y^5-x^2)$ is not smooth at the origin, while $\mathbb R = \mathbb A^1_{\mathbb R}$ is smooth anywhere.

Algebraically speaking this translates into $\mathbb R[t]$ being integrally closed and $\mathbb R[V] = \mathbb R[x,y]/(y^5-x^2)$ being not integrally closed, since we have the equation $\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2-y^3=0$ in the fraction field.

In particular there is no isomorphism between those domains.

While studying algebraic geometry, you should get used to such concepts. For this problem, we can also give a very elementary proof:

$\mathbb R[t]$ is well known to be a unique factorization domain. $\mathbb R[x,y]/(y^5-x^2)$ is not because $x$ is irreducible but not prime, since $$(\mathbb R[x,y]/(y^5-x^2))/(x) = \mathbb R[x,y]/(y^5-x^2,x) = \mathbb R[y]/(y^5)$$ is not a domain.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I can see that this is an elegant proof, but I am not very familiar with the concept of "integrally closed xx", and in particular it is a property preserved by isomorphism. I will need to check that and think about it.

Comment: For your statement about fraction field, it implies $\frac{x}{y}$ is integral over $\mathbb{R}[V]$. For $\mathbb{R}[V]$ to be integrally closed, we must have $\frac{x}{y}\in \mathbb{R}[V]$ which is not true. So $\mathbb{R}[V]$ is not integral closed. Is this the right argument? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is right.